# RequestDispatcher does not change URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've seen multiple question across the web in this topic, but I have some confusions. In my mini mvc: user click a link: `<a href="../TodaySaleServlet.do">Today Sale</a>` . This link will take the user to a servlet named `TodaySaleServlet.do` The data should be shown in `sale/Today_Sale.jsp`.

This is a servlet that will fetch data from model.

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    response.setContentType("");
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long first = cal.getTimeInMillis();



    String location = request.getSession(false).getAttribute("DBLOCATION").toString();
    String db = request.getSession().getAttribute("DBNAME").toString();
    System.out.println(location);
    System.out.println(db);

    SaleMaster sm = new SaleMaster(location, db);
    List<String> Sales = sm.Datewise(first, now);
    request.setAttribute("Sales", Sales);


    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("sale/Today_Sale.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);        
}
```

My **Today_Sale.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<c:import url ="../includes/header_2.jsp"/>


<div class="container">

    <h3 align="center">
        Today's Sale Report 
    </h3>

    <c:forEach var="Sale" items="${Sales}" >
    <c:out value="${Sale}"/>
            <br />
    </c:forEach>

</div>    


<%@include file="../includes/footer_1.jsp" %>
```

Now all the generated data is displaying in the servlet itself. I've googled about it, and found that `RequestDispatcher` will not change the url. I do not have any problem about the url, but the page displayed by the servlet has no formating and css and nothing.

How should I do it with proper way? How can I click a link and generate the servlet process and go to my expected jsp with proper url? Some say that I have to use `sendRedirect("someJSPFile")`. But in my case how?

Comment: Why can't you do that ?

Comment: how did you know its servlet it self because of URL is showing servlet Name??

Comment: Yes, I think so, the URL is the Servlet name.